# r: data.table count of elements with repetitions

Tags: r, count, data.table

I am a bit confused.
I have a datatable similar to that:

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(contract=c("c","c","c","d","d","d","d","f","f","f","f"),events=c("a","b","c","a","b","b","c","a","b","c","d"))


contract events
  c       a
  c       b
  c       c
  d       a
  d       b
  d       b
  d       c
  f       a
  f       b
  f       c
  f       d
```

And I would like to count the number of events by contract by keeping track of repetitions, so to end up with something like that:

```
contract events seqevents
      c       a       1
      c       b       2
      c       c       3
      d       a       1
      d       b       2
      d       b       2
      d       c       3
      f       a       1
      f       b       2
      f       c       3
      f       d       4
```

As a start, I tried to obtain a simple count of events by contract with this code, and then try to figure out a way to account for repetitions of the same event:

```
DT<-DT[ , seqevents := 1:.N , by = c("contract","events") ]
```

But the output is not correct, though it worked on a different data set.
Any suggestions on why it doesn't work and how can I get a count as illustrated above? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are we talking `DT[ , seqevents := .GRP , by = events]`? And please don't do that `DT <- DT` thingy there

Comment: If your data is sorted: `DT[, r := rleid(events), by=contract]`

Comment: Thanks, both work, but I do want my data to be sorted.